# Kickstart this hyperledger fabric application - Business problem

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have business problem where sellers sells some goods with their different buyers. in every purchase, seller is recording the transaction in their owne ledger and also recording the same transaction in a passbook that keeps with buyer only. So here buyer/seller anyone can manipulate the transaction and end of the day those ledgers will be out of sync. Eventually seller has to loose the money or buyer has to pay more money.

In this business transactions between seller & their different buyers, in order to avoid this kind of mutable ledger of transactions and to avoid loss of trust between buyer & seller, i am planning for an application that enforces the trust between the participant in the business network and also the ledger transactions immutable and the ledger itself is distributed.

This ledger is just to record the transactions in immutable way. Whenever seller is inserting a new transaction, it should be approved by buyer. Buyer should just have only the read access. Any buyer should not be able to see other buyers transactions.

As this is my business transaction, Hyper ledger came into my mind to implement it as blockchain network.

i am identifying Buyer & seller are two types of participants and recordEntry is the transaction in this network.

As buyers should cannot see other buyer's transactions, every buyer should be in one channel.

as buyers count increases with new customers coming to seller organization, how can a channel be created with dynamic participants?

how to identify the asset in this network?

Also please give me some references to kickstart this application

Thanks

Satya

Comment: can someone help me out

Comment: reposting the questions